# How can I use a sub-packages with Go on Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to use a helper package from Go Cloud Function. The package has some helper logic that can be shared between multiple functions. But, what is the right way to structure the packages so they all work? The package should be in the same project - not published and public as a completely separate package.

*I work at Google. The goal for this question is to proactively answer common questions and help developers starting off with Go on GCF.*

Comment: I know this has been answered before, but I went through a similar journey and wrote a post about it - maybe it helps https://medium.com/@rizwaniqbal/how-i-structure-cloud-functions-in-go-61e151b278ac

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use subpackages with [Go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules). Go modules are Go's new dependency management solution - they let you work outside of `GOPATH` and let you manage the exact versions of each dependency you have.

Modules also let you define a group of Go packages with the same import path prefix. When you're writing a function, this lets you import other packages in your module.

The function you're deploying needs to be at the root of your module.

Here is an example file structure and how packages would be imported:

```
.
├── cmd
│   └── main.go # Useful for testing. Can import and setup your function.
├── function.go # Can import example.com/foo/helperpackage
├── function_test.go
├── go.mod # module example.com/foo
└── helperpackage
    └── helper.go
```

This setup has your function in `function.go` and tested by `function_test.go`. They are in a module named `example.com/foo`. `helperpackage` can be imported by `function.go` using `example.com/foo/helperpackage`.

This also has a `cmd` directory, which may be helpful for local testing. You can import `example.com/foo` and start an HTTP server which registers your function as an HTTP handler. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "example.com/foo"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/HelloHTTP", foo.HelloHTTP)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Note: You *could* use a vendor directory to achieve the same result. But, all of the packages your function imports would need to be in the vendor directory (with the full import path), which works, but is cumbersome to maintain. It's uncommon to copy sub-packages into your vendor directory, so I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: I tried exactly as you described but I god the error: ```Deployment failure:
Build failed: go: finding cloud.google.com/go v0.40.0
go: finding rsc.io/binaryregexp v0.2.0
go: finding google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20190530194941-fb225487d101
files/restaurant/main.go:5:2: unknown import path "example/backend/database": cannot find module providing package example/backend/database
files/main.go:7:2: unknown import path "example/backend/proto": cannot find module providing package example/backend/proto```

Can you help?

Comment: What is your module name? The import should be prefixed with the name of your module (something like `example.com/example/backend/proto`).

Comment: @TylerBui-Palsulich I have a similar problem as Brian and took the time to write the detailed steps to reproduce, you can find it at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58722009/how-to-call-a-go-cloud-function-from-another-go-cloud-function-in-gcp

Comment: so how about a real life scenario, with more than 1 function? 
e.g. what if we need helperpackage in another gcf; another directory with cmd/main.go, function.go, etc.

Comment: This should be the part of actual documentation. It would have saved a couple of hours had I found this answer before.

Answer (score 6):

We also ran into this issue. The `go.mod` approach provided by @TylerBui-Palsulich (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54255486/2307346) didn't work as we also had to download dependencies from a private repository.

From the Google documentation:

> If your function's dependencies are hosted in a repository that is not publicly accessible, you must use a vendor directory to fetch your dependencies before deploying your function
>   (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-go#using_a_vendor_directory)

Given the following package structure:

```
cloudfunctions.go
sharedpackage
-> shared.go
go.mod
```

In our `go.mod` file we defined the following namespace: `module some/namespace`
The `cloudfunctions.go` file has the following package definition and imports

```
package foobar

import (
    "bitbucket.org/some/private/dependency"
    "some/namespace/sharedpackage"
)
```

Because of the private dependency we cannot use the go.mod file. Instead we provide a `vendor` directory.

> Warning: If you have both a go.mod file and a vendor directory at the root of your project, the contents of the vendor directory will be ignored when your function is built in the cloud. To ensure that your vendor directory is used, you must exclude the go.mod file from your project's source code prior to deployment. If you are using the gcloud command-line tool, you can ensure that go.mod is not uploaded by using .gcloudignore.
>   (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-go#using_a_vendor_directory)

`gcloud deploy` will ignore the vendor directory if it finds `go.mod`, we fix this with a `.gloudignore` file with the following content:

```
go.mod
go.sum
```

At the end we have the following file structure:

```
cloudfunctions.go
sharedpackage
-> shared.go
go.mod
vendor
.gcloudignore
```

#### The last step, Fixing the cannot find package error

When running the deploy step you will still run into an error similar to:

```
 (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: /tmp/sgb/gopath/src/serverlessapp/vendor/some/namespace/cloud_functions.go:5:2: cannot find package "some/namespace/sharedpackage" in any of:...
```

This is because the `go.mod` file, containing the module name, is ignored. now the Go compiler no longer knows that `some/namespace/sharedpackage` refers to the local `sharedpackage` directory.

We managed to get it working by changing the module name to match the package name:

Change module name in `go.mod` to `module foobar` 
Change the imports in `cloudfunctions.go` to: `"foobar/sharedpackage"`:

```
package foobar

import (
    "bitbucket.org/some/private/dependency"
    "foobar/sharedpackage"
)
```

Now the Go compiler is able to detect that `foobar/sharedpackage` is a subpackage of the `foobar` package.