# GCF deploy with local dependency

Tags: rest, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, go-modules

Let's say we have a code structure like this:

```
v1/
---api/
------pets/
---------create/
------------server.go
------------cmd/
---------------main.go
------------go.mod
------------go.sum
------------.gcloudignore
------------vendor/
---------get/
---------update/
---------delete/
------food/
---------create/
---------get/
---pkg/
------constants/
---------constants.go
------model/
---------pet.go
---------food.go
------store/
---------firestore.go
------validate/
---------header.go
------go.mod
------go.sum
```

every CRUD function directory (pets/get, food/create, etc) is the same structure as pets/create, so they all contain: server.go, cmd/main.go for testing, go.mod, go.sum, .gcloudignore and vendor/ of v1/pkg

*v1/api/pets/create/go.mod* contains:

```
module bitbucket.org/company/project/v1/api/pets/create

go 1.14

replace bitbucket.org/company/project/v1/pkg => ../../../pkg

require (
    bitbucket.org/company/project/v1/pkg v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
    github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go v1.1.0
)
```

*v1/api/pets/create/server.go* contains method that will be deployed to GCF

*.gcloudignore* contains go.mod and go.sum to ignore them while deploying

*v1/pkg* is vendored into every CRUD function/directory just like *v1/api/pets/create*

**PROBLEM**:
project is huge on production app, it contains (of course) much more methods with much more code, everything lags because those vendor dirs are ~4MB

How do I include v1/pkg into each of these CRUD folders? What is the easiest method you guys use?

**WHAT WE TRIED**:

- using private repo instead of local path -> not working while deploying
- using functions.go in root, with all functions defined there -> whole source code is uploaded for each function, we don't want that obviously
- using code from /pkg to each function separately (c/p) which is not maintainable and doesn't make any sense to do
- [How can I use a sub-packages with Go on Google Cloud Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255485/how-can-i-use-a-sub-packages-with-go-on-google-cloud-functions) -> this is not our use case, "helperpackage" should be somewhere upper in the tree

Comment: How do you deploy your functions?

Comment: position to v1/api/pets/create, then:

gcloud functions deploy <function_name> --trigger-http --runtime=go113 --entry-point=<method-name>

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic things that you can do. Something like your second try is the best one, but without using a function.go at the root directory

```
gcloud functions deploy --source=v1/api/pets/create <function_name> --trigger-http --runtime=go113 --entry-point=<method-name>
```

Uploading the whole project isn't a real problem because, in Go, only the compiled binary is kept and all the source files are trashed. So, no extra file will stay beside the binary.

However, if you really want to limit the uploaded code, you can use the [`--ignore-file=` parameter](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--ignore-file)

Comment: But that's exactly the problem, it is impossible to deploy code that has a dependency on something that is upper in the tree...

Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.                            
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: src/server/function.go:12:2: cannot find package "bitbucket.org/company/project/pkg/model" in any of:
 /usr/local/go/src/bitbucket.org/company/project/pkg/model (from $GOROOT)
 /workspace/src/bitbucket.org/company/project/pkg/model (from $GOPATH)